# Copy quotes between SoftLayer accounts

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using below code to retrieve existing quote for one account:

```
def getOrderContainer(quote_id):
    container = client['Billing_Order_Quote'].getRecalculatedOrderContainer(id=quote_id)
    return container
```

Which later I would like to "save" to another account.
I tried to use:

```
client['Billing_Order_Quote'].placeQuote(container)
```

but it throws an error message:

```
SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception): Object does not exist to execute method on. (SoftLayer_Billing_Order_Quote::placeQuote)
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that the method Billing_Order_Quote::placeQuote is not working, try using the method SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeQuote e.g.

```
container = client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].placeQuote(container)
```

The method should create the quote in the account and then you can use that quote to order however, you need to keep in mind that the prices may be different between accounts, because each account has its own catalog of prices. In case that the accounts have different catalog prices you will come across issues related to invalid prices.

Regards

Comment: Method client['SoftLayer_Product_Order'].placeQuote(container) did work, however I have came across another issue. Qoute that I am trying to copy from is customized, means that the price for networking part is doubled as my setup requires 4 uplinks instead of standard 2. Now when I copied the quote from one sub-account to another sub-account I am missing this extra network setup. I have also tried to update the quote on the new account with the missing part by getting the quote container, update the container manually and finally run placeQuote method again but this also seems have no effect.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? please copy the error

Comment: and I have another question using the control is your sub-account target (the account where you want to copy the quote) able to create a quote with the same configuration as the sub-account source? if the sub-account is not able to create the same quote configuration using the control portal, using the API will not change that.

Comment: I dont get any error, method placeQuote finishes OK, the problem is that the price is different from the original quote. Original quote have doubled price for the network part (edited manually by SL account manager) as I want 4 uplinks. I cannot edit the quote or change anything which makes sense as I could lower all the pricing and order. I'd rather thinking more about REST method to copy the quote 1:1 instead of checking the pricing catalog and adjusting container settings while executing placeQuote.

Comment: As I told the accounts may have differents prices and this may be that case if your sub-account target does not have the same price you are gonna come across with price issuess in the quote.

Comment: instead to copy quotes across accounts I think the best option is create a script which created new quotes for each account based in a list of items that you want with that approach you will avoid price issues.